# How to use streams for the logic with multiple conditional checks?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I am learning Java 11, and wanted to write the below logical block using Java 11. Any inputs would be helpful. As it has many conditional checks can we use lambda or streams to achieve the below logical block.

```
@Data
class MyDetails{
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private Integer spreadValue;
    private Object value;
    ...
}
```

```
public List<MyDetails> returnValidList(Collection<MyDetails> myDetails){
    for (MyDetails myDetail : myDetails){
        if (myDetail !=null && myDetail.getValue()!=null){
            if (myDetail.getSpreadValue()==3 || myDetail.getSpreadValue()==4){
                if (myDetail.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("AUTO") || myDetail.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("HOME")){
                   result.add(myDetail);
                } else {
                   result.add(myDetail);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I tried the below code, but the list size is zero, expected list size is 17. Any suggestion to correct the below snippet.

```
List<MyDetails> result = myDetails.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(obj -> Objects.nonNull(obj.getValue()))
    .filter(obj -> obj.getSpreadValue() == 3 || obj.getSpreadValue() == 4)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Providing the class structure would help a lot.

Comment: Edited the post, Its a normal utility class. @NikolasCharalambidis

Comment: I talk about the `MyDetails` class. How would the utility class help to get an answer?

Comment: why do you even need the innermost `if..else`, if you end up performing `result.add(myDetail);` as the only part of both?

Comment: @Naman - Yes, the inner if(..) block is not required. I have included the code which i had tried in the post above but list size is 0 instead of 17.

Comment: What might be interesting is to see the exact code without streams that you claim to be working for you. Without that one cannot really comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to chain the `filter` calls through the Stream API.

```
List<MyDetails> result = myDetails.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(obj -> Objects.nonNull(obj.getValue()))
    .filter(obj -> obj.getSpreadValue() == 3 || obj.getSpreadValue() == 4)
    .filter(obj -> obj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("AUTO") || obj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("HOME"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In more complex way, you might want to extract the condition(s) to a separate variables or methods (returning `Predicate<MyDetails>`. However, in case of advanced and configurable filtering, I recommend to iterate a collection of such predicated that can be filtered first before the application:

```
// Predicate list
List<Predicate<MyDetails>> predicates = List.of(
    Objects::nonNull, // should be always first
    obj-> Objects.nonNull(obj.getValue()),
    obj-> obj.getSpreadValue() == 3 || obj.getSpreadValue() == 4,
    obj-> obj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("AUTO") || obj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("HOME")
);

// Reduction using AND. If no predicate is qualified, 
// ... a predicate that everything passes through is returned (identity)
Predicate<MyDetails> predicate = predicates.stream()
    .reduce(obj -> true, Predicate::and);

// Apply the predicate
List<MyDetails> result = myDetails.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notes about the implementation:

- Stream API in this case is no improvement, except you want a configurable or advanced filtering.
- If you want to have configurable predicated, use `LinkedHashMap` and filter by keys the unwanted predicates.

And some code review as long as your code seems very imcomplete (ahtough I did my best to format it and make it clear):

- You miss another `return` in your method.
- `private Something value;` is missing in the `MyDetails` definition.
- The `List<MyDetails>` is undefined in the method (remember you call `getValue()`).
- `obj.getSpreadValue() == 3 || obj.getSpreadValue() == 4)` and `obj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("AUTO") || obj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("HOME")` are subjects of refactoring. I'd recommend to use `HashSet` and `Set::contains`.
- The condition checking for `AUTO` and `HOME` names is irrelevant since *both* branches results in the addition of the item to the list.

Comment: can we use Set::contains along with the stream() and filter you have mentioned at the beginning of the answer. I need to have both the conditional checks for AUTO and HOME . Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: I tried both the implementations you suggested above, the list size is zero, where as with my actual code the List size is 17.

Comment: the list size i'm getting is 0 when used stream and filter as stated in the above answer, any inputs?

Comment: @user3633028 the results of both codes might differ and it would be great if you could clarify [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202720/how-to-use-streams-for-the-logic-with-multiple-conditional-checks#comment115284170_65202720).. another aspect would be that `equalsIgnoreCase` cannot be directly transformed into `contains` over the elements of a `Set` unless ofcourse its exhaustive of all combination or the input is mapped to a specific case.

Comment: @Nikolas the `reduce` with identity would just be better than `orElse`.